# Unix Timestamp Conversion PHP - Wrong Date

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I'm trying to do something incredibly simple - convert a timestamp to a string in php with the date() function.

Code is as follows:

```
$test = date('d/m/y','1407974400000');
echo $test;
```

I expect the answer to be 14/8/14.

If I check on http://www.epochconverter.com/ that also gives this answer.

Yet the output produced from the above PHP is

```
07/12/86
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something completely stupid here - any able to help?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: `time()` for me currently outputs `1408013482`. You've got 3 digits too many. You should use seconds.

Comment: Did you get that value from javascript? Javascript timestamps are different to PHP for some reason I have yet to totally understand. They tend to be in micro seconds and if its from a smart phone it gets even weirder as android and apple js date timestamps are also bigger but also different to each other. There be Dragons.

Comment: Yes I did, the wider script is part of an AJAX call initiated by JS. I didn't know there were those differences so will look out of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had 3 zeros more, use seconds instead of milliseconds:

```
$test = date('d/m/y','1407974400');
echo $test;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use "seconds" not "milliseconds" on date function as timestamp.

```
$test = date('d/m/y','1407974400');
echo $test;
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I knew it was something stupid.